# No exception when node-amqp

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqp

I'm trying to use node-amqp.

When in the section of connection to rabbit an exception is thrown, I can get that exception but it restarts the connection to Rabbit forever.

Look at that:

```
    amqp = require("amqp")

    # Open a connection
    conn = amqp.createConnection( {url: "amqp://localhost"} , {reconnect: true})

    conn.on "ready", ->
      console.log "Conn Ready"

      conn.queue "queueX", {ack:true}, (queue) ->
        console.log "Subscribed #{queue.name}"

        assdsd() #calling non-exiting method. No exception is thrown but the connection is restarted
```

System loops on the errors thrown. I know this is because of {recconnect:true}. But I would like to be able to catch exceptions on my own. Any idea?

The output of my script is like this:

```
Conn Ready
Subscribed queueX
Conn Ready
Subscribed queueX
Conn Ready
Subscribed queueX
Conn Ready
Subscribed queueX
Conn Ready
Subscribed queueX
Conn Ready
Subscribed queueX
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have an error somewhere, this can help you

```
# listen for conn errors
conn.on 'error', (err) ->
  # print to check what went wrong
  console.error err.stack

  # exit script with error
  # http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code
  process.exit 1
```